# How to set exim accept incoming mail from only allowed hosts?

Tags: email, filter, exim

I have setup a mail gateway in front of exim. Bu sometimes, spammer may directly delivery mails to exim ip so spam mails passes mail gateway.
So I need to set a filter for SOME domains (in multidomain enviroment), to only accept mails from mail gateway only.
I can do that at server-wide with firewall. But in exim there are some domains not using mailgateway, so I need to do it at domain level in exim.
Any solution is welcome :)